# Can J# code run on JVM

Tags: j#

If I create a J# Application is there any way I can execute it on JVM as well

Answer (score 5):

No, J# programs are designed to run on the .NET platform. See the [J# FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/vjsharp/bb188604.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Yes - sort of. If the Java you write will compile using javac then you can have one source base and compile for both J# and Java. We do that for our reporting engine. If you do this on .net 40, you need [Calling J# code from .NET 4.0.](http://blogs.windwardreports.com/davidt/2011/02/calling-j-code-from-net-40.html)

But you cannot run the J# binary on a JVM.